# How to print all the duplicated elements of an array with how many times are repeated

Tags: arrays, c

So I have this problem I want my program to print all the duplicated elements of an array and the times they were repeated , I wrote the program so that the user enters then integer they are intrested to know how much it was repeated but I want it to print all the duplicated elements and the times of repetition without asking the user , for example :
array={1,4,1,5,2,6,4,4}
it prints : "The duplicates are 1:2 , 4:3)

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int arr[]= {1 , 4 , 5 , 9 , 7 , 1 , 8 , 1 , 5};
int x;
int s=0;
printf("Enter x = ");
scanf("%d",&x);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
if (x==arr[i])
        {
s++;
        }
  }
printf("%d:%d",x,s);
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the array (for example to *sort* it)? And what are the limits of the values inside the array?

Comment: If the array values are limited by some reasonable upper bound, you can create an array of that size that will hold counts for each value. Then simply print out the ones that have count more than 1.

Comment: You map each integer to a count. in c++ this  would be std::map<int, int>.

Comment: @Jane If you want then do it!:)

Comment: The easiest way is to _sort_ the array. Then, a simple loop through the array can show the duplicates. As S.P.D. asked, can you sort the array (or a copy of the array)? Otherwise, you'd need to create a histogram/frequency table. Then, we'd need to know the lowest value and the highest value. If the values are arbitrary (i.e. can span the entire range of integers), then sorting is the only sure way unless the histogram is implemented as (e.g.) a linked list.

Comment: @CraigEstey No we're not allowed to sort it , the array is given and we're told to respect the given order of its elements. Thanks a lot for the idea I'll try it as an alternative way of solving the problem.

Comment: Then perhaps create a *copy* of the array, one that you can sort and modify as you'd like? While adding some overhead, it might be the simplest solution.

Comment: And please take the time to include all your assignment requirements and limitations inside your question. Like the range of the values, the size of the array, etc. That will make it much easier to help you with a good solution.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).